# Display Simple Google Chart From C# List

Tags: c#, list, charts

Hi I'm trying to create a simple bar chart from a database query which outputs to a List

The C# is a simple list that pulls through "OSName" and "OS Count" and then converts to JSON Data.

```
List<string> googleDataset = new List<string>();
 foreach(DataRow row in dsAssets.Rows)
        
            {
                   googleDataset.Add("['" + row["OSNAME"] +  "', " + row["OS Count"] + "]");
            }
  var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(googleDataset);
```

I just cant find the correct Javascrript code to display this data in a Google Chart, the data that is created in the GoogleDataset List looks like :

> ['Win 2008 R2', 51]['Win 2016', 10]['Win 10', 4]['Win 2008', 4]['Win 7', 53]['Win 2012 R2', 22]['Win 10', 38]['Win 8.1', 1]['Win 10', 30]['Win 10', 8]['Win 10', 2]['Win 2008 R2', 2]['Win 2016', 3]['Win 7', 3]['Win 2012 R2', 1]['Win 10', 1]['Win 7', 2]['Win 2008 R2', 1]

Does anyone have an example of how I would accomplish this please ?

Cheers

Andy

Comment: so the output you want to have from "jsonData" should look like the one you posted? 
['Win 2008 R2', 51]['Win 2016', 10]['Win 10', 4]...
but what you get is [['Win 2008 R2', 51],['Win 2016', 10],['Win 10', 4]...] ?

Comment: Yes I believe so , I'm not very familiar with Google charts ?

Comment: isn't this just what you are looking for? https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start
or are you just having trouble converting the json string to an array than this might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/json/parse
otherwise please provide more info on what you currently have and what your goal is.

Comment: Thank you for you help , I managed to fix the formatting by adding some "clean-up" and formatting with JSON :                                                                                                        
GoogleData = "<%=GoogleChartData%>";
GoogleData = queryObject.trim();
            GoogleData = queryObject.replace(/'/g, '"');
            GoogleData = jQuery.parseJSON(queryObject);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(GoogleData);

Answer (score 1):

```
GoogleData = "<%=GoogleChartData%>";
GoogleData = GoogleData .trim();
GoogleData = GoogleData .replace(/'/g, '"');
GoogleData = jQuery.parseJSON(GoogleData);
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(GoogleData);
```